# How do I get jQuery $.ajax to download an XLSX document?

Tags: jquery

I currently have this markup with two links and I'm trying to have both called via AJAX.

I have a search which runs a query based on the start and end date used, and I have an export to Excel link that I'm trying to have download an Excel document with the start and end date used.

Everything works fine except for getting the `#export` `$.ajax` call to download the Excel document.

How can I get jQuery to download an Excel document?

```
<a href="#" class="buttonH bBlue" id="export">Export to Excel</a>
<a href="#" class="buttonH bBlue" id="search">Search</a>
<div class="headInput" id="reportsDateSearch">
    <input type="text" name="start_date" placeholder="<%= @end_date %>" class="datepicker" id="endDate" />
    <input type="text" name="end_date" placeholder="<%= @start_date %>" class="datepicker" id="startDate" />            
</div>
```

jQuery AJAX calls:

```
// This call gets the data based on the start and end date used
    $('#search').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
            },
            url: '<%= reports_affirmative_action_path %>',
            data: {start_date: $('#startDate').val(), end_date: $('#endDate').val()}
        }, null, 'script');
    });


// This call gets the data based on the start and end date used, but i'm trying to get it to return the xlsx format.
    $('#export').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                },
                url: '<%= reports_affirmative_action_path(:format => :xlsx) %>',
                data: {start_date: $('#startDate').val(), end_date: $('#endDate').val()}
        }, null, 'script');
    });
```

Comment: Do you want a download dialog presented to the user? or are you trying to get the csv for use in jQuery.

Comment: Usually with a download dialog, you just use a server-side script to send the appropriate headers, including the mime-type - can jQuery facilitate a download dialog?  I understand it could send the request, but the actual download is based on the server-side script.

Comment: If you want a download dialog, don't use ajax. Just update the href of the clicked element to include the url parameters and return true.

Comment: Just figured that out before I looked at your comment @Kevin. Can you post that as an answer so I can give cred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just update the href of the clicked anchor tag.

```
$('#export').on('click', function() {
    this.href = "<%= reports_affirmative_action_path(:format => :xlsx) %>?" + 
        $.param({start_date: $('#startDate').val(), end_date: $('#endDate').val()});
});
```